# I created an .app file using py2applet but it appears on dock for 1 millisecond and disappears

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, py2app, python-3.9

I compiled my .py file into a distributable .app file using py2app but when I click on the app icon it appears on dock for a millisecond and disappears. Any idea why?

I have tried using chmod 777 and 755 to attempt and allow permissions to execute this file but no lock :(.

Help